# How to monitor PHP Laravel web application processes?

Tags: php, performance, laravel, load-balancing, shared-hosting

I would like to know how could I monitor my web application processes locally? This is because my production site on my current hosting (*bluehost*), it is showing several processes for my web app and api (around 35 - 40) which cause the application to load infinitely.

When I am running it on my local machine, there's no problem and the application works flawlessly. It is too hard to replicate the scenario since it only occurs on my web hosting. I have several websites hosted there and it seems that only my Laravel application has the issue. My wordpress and Codeigniter apps works smoothly.

I have contacted support already and according to them, it is regarding the code that caused the performance issue but I do not see any mistake in my code since it works fast on my local.

I already used caching for it, routes and database, yet problem still persists.

Comment: what OS are you running on with bluehost you can run PS and see whats running TOP will be helpful if these processes are high on server load and if you are running on a *nix.

Comment: sad to say that im running it on a shared hosting. I've never encountered this issue before, just recently. I've had the application for almost a year already with 1000++ users daily and no trouble with regards to site performance.

Comment: ask the hosting provider for  a snapshot of the processes, i would suggest getting a cheap vps you would be better off with that than shared hosting.

Comment: I wanted to replicate the problem on local first and see if it is a code or hosting problem. Would there be a process monitoring tool that I can use to be able to monitor it on my local? I am running xampp in windows.

Comment: process manager i would assume, just keep in mind youre not going to get all of the traffic that you currently have on your live production site.

Answer (score 0):

try running `$ php artisan optimize` in deployment and ensure that `Config::get('app.debug')` is not true.